# Error in modulegen creation in Hybris 6.7

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I've created a **b2c_b2b_acc** recipe. Now when I try to create modulegen, I'm facing the following error,

```
Java.util.regex.patternSyntacexception: illegal repetition near index 0 ${YMODULE_TOKEN}(.*)
```

Comment: In expert forum, same question answered as unzipping to new folder and retrying.

Comment: please add more of the stacktrace information and the invocation command (did you do it interactively or all parameters as part of the command)?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use recipe - run the command  ant modulegen or extgen, instead of choosing default [accelerator], choose the template related to your needs (b2baccelerator).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the installer directory, for example: C:\hybris\installer.
If you don't know the name of your installer recipe, you can verify it in the recipes directory, for example: C:\hybris\installer\recipes.

For more details about the installer recipes, see [Installer Recipe Reference](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/f09d46cf4a2546b586ed7021655e4715.html).

Install the SAP Hybris Commerce flavor using the required recipe by entering the following command:

> On Windows: install.bat -r
>
> On Linux or Mac: ./install.sh -r

To install SAP Hybris Commerce with B2C Accelerator, enter the following command:

> On Windows: install.bat -r b2c_acc
>
> On Linux or Mac: ./install.sh -r b2c_acc

Refer to the readme.txt file provided in the recipe folder for specific instructions on how to install the flavor of SAP Hybris Commerce that your require. Some recipes include additional instructions to install or initialize SAP Hybris Commerce.

More info [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c46c266866910149666a0fe4caeee4e.html).